# How to source Page Scoped ID (PSID) from FB Messenger in Power Virtual Agents (PVA)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, messenger, power-virtual-agents

I'm using Microsoft Power Virtual Agent bot that I created and linking to a Facebook page and Messenger bot.  I want to be able to extract the page source ID (PSID) from the initial webhook callback from Messenger to PVA so that I can build a PVA automate flow to call the Messenger User Profile API to pull some contextual information about the person I'm chatting with on the bot.  But I'm not able to find anything anywhere about how to do this.  Any ideas?

I've read the User Profile API and have attempted to create a Power Automate flow using the HTTP request container, but this can't be used inside a Power Virtual Agent.  I'm assuming this information is being stored somewhere (Dataverse? A PVA or Power Apps object?) but have no clue where.